# I can't select images from my gallery for upload (android studio)

Tags: java, android, gallery, imagebutton

i'm learning to program in Android Studio, i'm making a App with Firebase watching tutorials, in this part https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tG6Vqi7Ur9A (is a video of only 4 min of duration) i follow the instructions of tutorial but when I run the App in the emulator and try select a image from my gallery doing click in the ImageButton the images appears translucent or greys, I tried to click on them but never is selected, it's disabled to select.

I clarify that I hadn't images in my emulator so I dragged them from the desktop to the android emulator, so now if it appear, I don't know if this influences. I added this to MANIFEST,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>﻿
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>﻿
```

but it doesn't work.

My Layout for add images

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_post"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.social.socialpart.socialpart.PostActivity">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/post"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<EditText
    android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="title"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/CreatePost_title" />

<EditText
    android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CreatePost_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/CreatePost_description" />

<Button
    android:text="Submit post"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Publicar_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

My Java Class

```
    public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton mSlectImage;
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST=1;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    mSlectImage=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mSlectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("Image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
 });
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageUri=data.getData();
        mSlectImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

}
```

}

I'm sorry, hope you understand me, my english is regular.

Comment: "I added this to MANIFEST" -- there are no permissions named `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` in Android. "it doesn't work" -- please explain **in detail** what "it doesn't work" means. What are your exact symptoms? Beyond that, use a correct MIME type (`image/*`, not `Image/*`).

Comment: @CommonsWare I realized that these permissions don't exist, but I'm a newbie and wanted to try because nothing works. When I say  "it doesn't work", I mean that I still can't select an image from the gallery from my application, when I click on an image I simply do not see anything, nor an error on the console, it's as if I was clicking nothing.

Comment: Set breakpoints or use `Log` statements to confirm that your `onActivityResult()` method is getting called, and see what the value of `imageUri` is if you are getting called.

Comment: Thanks! I changed Image/* for image/* and it worked. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton mSlectImage;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
        mSlectImage=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        mSlectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });
        private void chooseImage()
        {
            Intent galleryIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
        } 
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

            if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri imageUri=data.getData();
                mSlectImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
```

Comment: plz copy and paste the i had made changes there plz notify me if m wrong

Answer (score 0):

As an option , you can try another way

```
Val intent = Intent(Intent_ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(intent, 111)
```

This is the simple way to access gallery

The rest code on `onActivityResult`
You can follow as it is in your picture , (but slightly change between **Kotlin** and **java** )